# How to form nested ternary statements in a parent if condition and individual if conditions

Tags: javascript

```
let soup = "abc";
let customerBanned = false;

let result = customerBanned ? "no soup" : soup ? `good ${soup} soup` : "bad soup";
```

I have translated the above ternary statements as follows:

```
if (customerBanned) {
    return "no soup";
}
else {
    if (soup) {
        return `good ${soup} soup`;
    }
    else {
        "bad soup";
    }   
}
```

But the following similarly written ternary statement is resulting in different if else conditions.

```
let myScore = 79;
let myGrade = myScore > 80 ? "A" : myScore > 60 ? "B" : myScore > 50 ? "C" : "D";
```

Here is my translation:

```
if(myScore > 80) {
    return "A";
}
else if(myScore > 60) {
    return "B";
}
else if(myScore > 50) {
    return "C";
}
else {
    return "D";
}
```

**Which translation can be used for nested if else statements and why?**

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the translations work similar to their corresponding nested-ternary-operator expressions, save for an extra variable; `if (cond1) { a } else if (cond2) { b } else { c }` is exactly the same as `if (cond1) { a } else {` `if (cond2) { b } else { c }` `}`, just less nested. What *exactly* is this question about? Comparing those? Whether they works? Something else?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You have two different sets of conditions for two different things, and are asking why they are different? Also, you already have translated code that uses nested if else statements, so why are you asking if it can be used via nested if else statements?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl Can't you run them yourself and find out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first could be translated to one without `else` statements, because of previous `return` statements ([*early return pattern*](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/early-return-dip-ghosh), [Should a function have only one return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement)):

```
if (customerBanned) return "no soup";
if (soup) return `good ${soup} soup`;
return "bad soup";
```

Second one:

```
if (myScore > 80) return "A";
if (myScore > 60) return "B";
if (myScore > 50) return "C";
return "D";
```

Comment: What ternary statements can be written to include 'else'?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl the else part is all behind `:`. do you have some code which highlight the problem?

Comment: `the else part is all behind :` I understand that. I do request you to write same code with explicit 'else' over there too just for my understanding.

Comment: sorry, i have no idea. please add some more examples to the question. what goes wrong?

Comment: I myself have attempted to translate these ternary statements in the question. Are my translations correct?

Comment: your assumption is right. the first one could omit the block after elese, because following `if` is a single statement.